# Proving there exists a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function and let $T_f: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $S_f: [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined as:

$$T_f(x) = 1+\int_{0}^{x} f(s) ds\\ S_f(x) = \begin{cases} f(x+1/2) \ \text{if } x < 1/2 \\ f(1) \ \text{if } x \ge 1/2  \end{cases}$$

Furthermore, define $W_f = \alpha T_f + \beta S_f$ for some real numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

> Prove that if $|\alpha| + |\beta|<1$, then there exists a continuous
>   function $f: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $W_f = f$.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you managed to work out what $f$ must be but not the proof or do you not even know what the answer is? Have you solved the problem for any specific values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$? Any nontrivial values?

Comment: Perhaps you could find a suitable $f$ for $\beta=0,\,\alpha=\frac12$? What about $\beta=0$ in general?

Comment: To be honest, I really don't know where to even start for this proof :( Normally, I leave any kind of attempt I made in my posts, but for this question, I really am stumped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Banach's fixed point theorem [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem) in the space $C([0,1])$. You have
$$|W_f(x)-W_g(x)|\le |\alpha| \int_0^x|f(s)-g(s)|\,ds+|\beta||S_f(x)-S_g(x)|
\le (|\alpha|+|\beta|)\Vert f-g\Vert_\infty$$ and so
$$\Vert W_f-W_g\Vert_\infty\le  (|\alpha|+|\beta|)\Vert f-g\Vert_\infty$$

Comment: Thanks, I understand, but just a bit lost towards the end, can you spell out the details of how you arrived at the inequality $|\alpha| \int_0^x|f(s)-g(s)|\,ds+|\beta||S_f(x)-S_g(x)|
\le (|\alpha|+|\beta|)\Vert f-g\Vert_\infty$ ?

Comment: $|\alpha| \int_0^x|f(s)-g(s)|\,ds \le |\alpha| \int_0^x\Vert f-g\Vert_\infty\,dx\le |\alpha|\Vert f-g\Vert_\infty 1$. Also $|f(x+\frac12)-g(x+\frac12)|\le \Vert f-g\Vert_\infty$ and $|f(1)-g(1)|\le \Vert f-g\Vert_\infty$.

Comment: Great, that helps so much! Very thorough explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Let's first try to work out what $f$ is. We'll expand the equation $f = W_f$:
$$f(x) = \alpha\left(1+\int_0^xf(s)\mathrm ds\right) + \beta S_f(x)$$
And now we'll differentiate it:
$$f'(x) - \alpha f(x) = \beta S_f'(x).\tag{1}$$

Now we need to work out what $S_f'(x)$ is. So we think very hard and we write down
$$S_f'(x) = \left\{ \begin{matrix}f'\left(x+\frac12\right)&x\le\frac12\\0&x\ge\frac12\end{matrix}\right.$$
It would probably be nice if both cases held at $x=\frac12$ but we only need $f$ to be continuous and not differentiable (everywhere).

It looks like we can solve equation $(1)$ for $x>\frac12$ as $f'=\alpha f$ so $f=A\mathrm e^{\alpha x}$. Now we can write down what $f'(x+\frac12)$ is for $x\in\left[0,\frac12\right]:$
$$f'(x)-\alpha f(x)=\alpha\beta A\mathrm e^{\alpha x}\mathrm e^{\frac\alpha2}.\tag{2}$$

We know then that the solution to this will look like $f=(A+Bx)\mathrm e^{\alpha x}$ so we solve for $B$ to get $B=\alpha\beta A \mathrm e^{\frac\alpha2}.$ We can now write down the solution so far:
$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
A\left(1+\alpha\beta x \mathrm e^{\frac\alpha2}\right)\mathrm e^{\alpha x} & x<\frac12
\\
A'\mathrm e^{\alpha x} & x>\frac12
\end{matrix}\right.$$

We now put in the continuity condition to get $A'=A\left(1+\frac12\alpha\beta\mathrm e^{\frac\alpha2}\right)$

Finally the boundary conditions were lost when we differentiated $f=W_f$ so let's put those in to work out what $A$ is.
\begin{align*}
f(0)&=\alpha+\beta f(1)\\
A &=\alpha + \beta A\left(1+\frac12\alpha\beta\mathrm e^{\frac\alpha2}\right)\mathrm e^\alpha\\
A &= \frac{-2\alpha}{2-2\beta\mathrm e^\alpha - \alpha\beta^2\mathrm e^{\frac32\alpha}}
\end{align*}

This seems to be what the solution looks like. There may well be mistakes in the working. The next steps are:

1. To simplify the above
2. To show that the function is continuous
3. To show that the function satisfies the desired equation
4. To show that the function is well defined
5. To show that these are all true so long as $|\alpha|+|\beta|<1$

Comment: what is the point of any of this when the functions involved are not diffrentiable?

Comment: We only need to find some $f$ so we can choose it to be differentiable everywhere except at $\frac12$. Then we only need to check for continuity at $\frac12$ as differentiability implies it elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily shown using the [Banach fixed-point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem). All we need to do is show that $$W: C([0,1]) \rightarrow C([0,1]): f\mapsto W_f$$ is a contraction, i.e.:
$$\lVert W_f - W_g\rVert \leq c\lVert f- g\rVert$$
where $0<c<1$ (in this case $c=|\alpha|+|\beta|$ works) and with a suitable norm (in this case the supremum norm works).
Then the banach fixed-point theorem tells you there is a unique fixed-point, so a unique function $f \in C([0,1])$ such that $W_f = f$